# Clipping images into different shapes like triangle, pentagon in html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am developing a game in `html 5` canvas where I have to clip images into many shapes. I also want to join these clipped images using `mouse events`. Can I only clip a square shape? Also, is it necessary to save x and y co-ordinates of each clipped image to know its position or is there any alternate way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example to illustrate how to:

- clip an image into 4 triangle pieces,
- hit-test the pieces,
- move the pieces using your mouse

[image]

Here's code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/r59ch/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var $canvas=$("#canvas");
    var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var scrollX=$canvas.scrollLeft();
    var scrollY=$canvas.scrollTop();

    var isDown=false;
    var startX;
    var startY;

    var parts=[];
    var selectedPart=-1;

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=function(){
        var cx=img.width/2;
        var cy=img.height/2;
        var w=img.width;
        var h=img.height;
        parts.push({x:25,y:25,points:[{x:0,y:0},{x:cx,y:cy},{x:0,y:h}]});
        parts.push({x:25,y:25,points:[{x:0,y:0},{x:cx,y:cy},{x:w,y:0}]});
        parts.push({x:125,y:25,points:[{x:w,y:0},{x:cx,y:cy},{x:w,y:h}]});
        parts.push({x:25,y:25,points:[{x:0,y:h},{x:cx,y:cy},{x:w,y:h}]});
        drawAll();
    }
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/house100x100.png";

    function drawAll(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        for(var i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
            draw(parts[i]);
        }
    }

    function draw(part){
        ctx.save();
        define(part);
        ctx.clip();
        ctx.drawImage(img,part.x,part.y);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function hit(part,x,y){
        define(part);
        return(ctx.isPointInPath(x,y))
    }

    function move(part,x,y){
        part.x+=x;
        part.y+=y;
        draw(part);
    }

    function define(part){
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(part.x,part.y);
        ctx.beginPath();
        var point=part.points[0];
        ctx.moveTo(point.x,point.y);
        for(var i=0;i<part.points.length;i++){
            var point=part.points[i];
            ctx.lineTo(point.x,point.y);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousedown stuff here
      for(var i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
          if(hit(parts[i],startX,startY)){
              isDown=true;
              selectedPart=i;
              return;
          }
      }          
      selectedPart=-1;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseup stuff here
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mouseOut stuff here
      isDown=false;
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      if(!isDown){return;}
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // Put your mousemove stuff here
      var dx=mouseX-startX;
      var dy=mouseY-startY;
      startX=mouseX;
      startY=mouseY;
      //
      var part=parts[selectedPart];
      move(part,dx,dy);
      drawAll();


    }

    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});


}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h4>Drag the right triangle-image into place</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a path and use that for clipping:

```
ctx.save();    /// store current state of canvas incl. default clip mask

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 10);
ctx.lineTo(200, 10);
ctx.lineTo(100, 110);
ctx.clip();    /// will close the path implicit

/// draw graphics here

ctx.restore(); /// restore default infinite clipping mask
```

This will create a triangle. If you now draw on top the graphics will be clipped to this shape. Coordinates given here are of course just for example.

A small note: the different browsers may or may not anti-alias the clipping mask. If not the result may turn out "hard-edged".

(I recommend to use `save()`/`restore()` in connection with `clip()`. There is suppose to be a `resetClip()` method but this is rarely implemented in the browsers and is currently considered for removal from the specs.)

An alternative to using `clip()` is to use image pattern. Define a pattern with the image you want to clip, then create the path as above and use `fill()` with the pattern set as `fillStyle`. For this to work properly you need to `translate()` the canvas before filling to place the image pattern in the desired position.